# The Forgot password link overlaps the Safari autofill icon

Tags: bug, design, login, safari

On the log in page, there is a forgot password link inside the Password text field. I'm using Safari 9 on Mac, and it offers a password autofill feature that appears as a key icon in the same position, making it impossible to use on your website.[image: forgot password and autofill overlap]